# How can i solve this error in my python code?

Tags: python

```
def almost_there(n): 
    list=[x for x in range(90,111)]
    list_1=[i for i in range(190,211)]
    if n in list or list_1: 
        return True 
    else:
        return False
print(almost_there(1))
>>> True
```

Why is it giving true even when the value is 1?

Comment: The second part of the if statement is list_1 which return true as long as the list is not None or empty, therefore you will always return True

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Some tips: 1. Don't use `list` as a variable name -- it's a builtin function. 2. Why use a list comprehension to make a list from a list? `range()` returns a list, no need to transform it. 3. No need to use `if boolean: return True else: return False` logic. Just use `return boolean`

Comment: Actually, I wasn't correct that `range()` returns a `list` (though that was true before Python 3). But it does return an iterable, and that's all that's needed here. If you really did need a list you could say `list(range(...))` (assuming you didn't redefine `list`).

Answer (score 2):

Because of the condition:
`if n in list or list_1:`

When you have or condition, both part of the condition should be `False` for the condition to be False

In your case:
`n is not in list` is False , but `list_1` is not empty and is True.

So you have
`if False or True:`  -- and this returns True (the condition is fulfilled)

Comment: if i try if in list or if in list2 , then ?

Comment: For n = 1, you will have `if False or False:` and it will return False

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```py
def almost_there(n): 
    list_1 = [x for x in range(90,111)]
    list_2 = [i for i in range(190,211)]
    
    if n in list_1 or n in list_2: 
        return True 
    else:
        return False

print(almost_there(1))
# False
```

Check if n is either in `list_1` or `list_2`. If you do `if n in list_1 or list_2` this will only check if `n` is in `list_1` and not `list_2`.
One more thing don't use `list` as your variable name. That will override the `list()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you `if` statement.

`if n in list or list_1:`  evaluates to: 1) `if n in list` (false) `or` 2) `if list_1` (true)

Now the second argument is always going to be `True` because it's a populated list.

The correct way to write your `if` statement should be: `if (n in list or n in list_1)`

This evaluates to `if` 1) `n in list` (false) `or` 2) `n in list_1` (false)

And thus you 'll get the expected results.